# Does Veins implements both SNR and SINR calculations in the Veins simulations?

Tags: omnet++, veins, mixim

I wonder if in Veins both SNR and SINR is calculated for the received frames?

I see both terms in veins physical layer implementation files.
I am confused if they mean the same thing or they have different purpose?
I could find the SINR threshold (i.e,-65dBm) and the formula (i.e., sinr=signal/(interference+noise)) but couldn't find any threshold level for SNR.

So really confused if,
the SNR is only for Preamble (or may be PLCP header) and the SINR is for the payload (or may be for the whole frame)?
Or SINR is calculated for both time that is, when the signal is received and later when the whole frame is received (with possible interferers)?

Please also share if there are any references to where i can find details on this matter?

Please help!

Thanks in advance,
/MM

Answer (score 0):

SINR is the ratio of Signal to Interference+Noise, SNR is the ratio of of Signal to Noise (that is, ignoring interference). Both are calculated to keep track of frames that could not be decoded because the SINR was too bad, but that could have been decoded if interference was ignored. We call this a "collision". You can find the corresponding source code in Veins 5.2 at https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/veins-5.2/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc#L224