# SINR and SNR thresholds in Veins

Tags: c++, omnet++, veins

I was trying to find the required **SINR** and **SNR** thresholds in order to process the signal in Veins, have searched for that through the *.ned* and input *.xml* files but couldn't find them. What are these thresholds and where I should look for them?

Answer (score 0):

You can find the values calculated for SNIR and SNR at line no.123,124 in
/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc

```
double sinrMin = SignalUtils::getMinSINR(start, end, frame, airFrames, noise);
double snrMin;
```

Refer online at https://github.com/sommer/veins/blob/c96edc2be25266300f73bd701ee33f4acb662631/src/veins/modules/phy/Decider80211p.cc

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71482303/7215379 gives more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
As I know this function calculates the sinr for the received signal, but I'm looking for the threshold, I mean after calculation how it decides if the calculated sinr value is greater than the required threshold or not. I suppose it should be a predefined value in some configuration files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71482303/7215379 explains what is available in veins.